# Узнать объём оперативной памяти

Tags: perl

Всем привет! Кто знает как на perl узнать объём оперативной памяти как под linux так и под Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы думаете, что Perl - это такая волшебная штука, которая может делать что угодно, то зря :) Смотрите в сторону средств вашей OS. Под линуксом, например, вполне укладывается в задачу парсинг вывода `cat /proc/meminfo`. Но это настолько примитивно делается на Perl, что особо обсуждать и нечего :)

P.S. Впрочем, для тех, кого забанили в гугле, есть, например, [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=meminfo&mode=all).